# How to save form with multiple foreignkey

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have list of posts in newfeeds from different users, I am trying to implement a report form so that when i click on the ellipsis on a user post and click report, then a modal popup with list of options like "Hate Speech, Violence, etc.." when selected an option and click on submit button, I want both the user who is reporting and user reported to be saved in admin. Request.user (queen_glory) is saved in admin but the user_is_reported (the user's post you're reporting) is empty, i want that user also be saved in admin. How can i do this using one form?

[image]

[image]

Model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    poster_profile = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL) 

class Report(models.Model):
    user_is_reporting = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_reporting', blank=True,null=True)
    user_is_reported = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_reported', null=True, blank=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='reports', null=True, blank=True)
    why_reporting = models.TextField(blank=True)
    reporting_user_for = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Form:

```
REPORT_POST_CHOICES = (
('Nudity', 'Nudity'),
('Violence', 'Violence'),
('Hate speech or symbols', 'Hate speech or symbols'),
('Harassment or Bullying', 'Harassment or Bullying'),
('Suicide or Self-Injury', 'Suicide or Self-Injury'),
('Sale of illegal or regulated goods', 'Sale of illegal or regulated goods'),
('False information', 'False information'),
('I just do not like it', 'I just do not like it'),
)
class ReportPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    reporting_user_for = forms.ChoiceField(label='',widget=forms.RadioSelect, 
choices=REPORT_POST_CHOICES)
    class Meta:
        model = Report
        fields = (
            'reporting_user_for',
        )
        exclude = ('why_reporting', 'user_is_reporting', 'user_is_reported',)
```

Views:

```
@login_required
def home_view(request):
    #All posts in new feed
    all_images = Post.objects.filter(
        Q(poster_profile=request.user, active=True)|
        Q(poster_profile__from_user__to_user=request.user, active=True)|
        Q(poster_profile__to_user__from_user=request.user, active=True)|
        Q(poster_profile__profile__friends__user=request.user, active=True)).distinct().exclude(
        Q(hide_post=request.user, active=True)|
        Q(poster_profile__profile__blocked_users__user=request.user, active=True))

#Report user post form
if request.method == "POST":
    print(request.POST)
    post_id = request.POST.get("my_post")
    post_obj = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
    reportpost_form = ReportPostForm(request.POST)
    if reportpost_form.is_valid():
        rp = reportpost_form.save(commit=False)
        rp.user_is_reporting = request.user
        rp.user_is_reported = what should be here? #How do I pass the id of user_is_reported here? 
        rp.post = post_obj
        rp.save()  
        return redirect('/')
else:
    reportpost_form = ReportPostForm()  
context = {'all_images': all_images, 'reportpost_form':, reportpost_form'}
return render(request,'home.html', context)
```

Template:

```
<div class="modal fade animated flipInX" id="reportuserModal{{post.pk}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" aria-labelledby="settingsModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
<div class="modal-content mx-auto" style="width:80%;">

<div class="card">
<div class="card-header mb-3">
<h5 class="font-weight-normal text-center" style="font-size:16px;">
You can report user after selecting a problem.
</h5>
</div>

<form method="POST" class="reportuser-form">
{% csrf_token %}

<input type="hidden" value={{post.id}} name="my_post">
{{ reportpost_form }}
                            
<div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
Report
</button>
<button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-amber btn-sm">
Cancel
</button>
</div>
</form>

</div>                          
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to find out for which post the report button was clicked? If so then you can query out who posted this and save his id maybe?

Comment: @Shahriar... You have a point, but I am finding it difficult to query for that particular user who made the post. I just updated my question with Post model. See if you can help me with the queries.

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
if reportpost_form.is_valid():
    rp = reportpost_form.save(commit=False)
    rp.user_is_reporting = request.user

    rp.user_is_reported = User.object.filter(is_superuser=True).first()

    rp.post = post_obj
    rp.save()  
    return redirect('/')
```

Comment: It save the superuser in admin, not saving the right user.